# Installshield Suite Update URL prompt

Tags: installshield, installshield-2014

Currently when i enter the Update URL and that is triggered by the Setup.exe application, the user has no choice but to download the update. There is no prompt to the user as IF they would like to perform the update first or not, they are simply forced to download the update when one is found. My exe is 430MB so i don't want them to be forced to download that if they don't want to. Is there a way to intercept the check and ONLY download/update the exe if the user answers YES to a prompt? I see in the /debuglog file that the URL is checked than immediately starts the download and displays the 'ISDownloadProgress' dialog. But also shows that the 'InstallationWelcome' dialog is shown as well even though it is not. It must be hidden somehow i guess.

Comment: You can add one CustomAction which ask user to download/install an updates. Set the property for this user input and accordingly you can call your updates. You just need to call this CustomAction at the time of Upgrade only by setting a condition to CustionAction.

Answer (score 0):

The Update URL setting is best suited for a downloading setup launcher which is itself quite small. Since downloading setup launchers can be invalidated if the resources they fetch are moved or removed, it doesn't let the user choose whether to get the updated launcher.

Since this behavior is not currently optional, you could file an enhancement request with the support team, or you could write a wrapper that performs a similar check.

Comment: Can i capture any/all of the cmdline parameters that may have been provided to the exe prior to the upgrade download taking place and restarting the new exe?

Comment: I thought we passed the original command line on to the updated suite, but I would have to verify. It should be easy for you to check that out.

Comment: You pass it on the updated suite. I meant if i create my own solution via c# code, could i somehow access that cmdline variable somehow. Then i dont have to parse anything, i could just pull it right in and execute the new file..